# Angular 2 array extract specific data by id

Tags: angular

How can i extract specific data from the array with the id and use it in the div.

home.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeProjectComponent } from './home-project.component';
import { NewsletterComponent } from './../shared/newsletter/newsletter.component';

export class Project {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  status: string;
}

const PROJECTS: Project[] = [
  { id: 1,
    name: 'name1',
    title: 'title1',
    status: 'status1'
  },
  { id: 2,
    name: 'name2',
    title: 'title2',
    status: 'status2'
  },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'name3',
    title: 'title3',
    status: 'status3'
  },
....
{ id: 100,
    name: 'name100',
    title: 'title100',
    status: 'status100'
  },
];


@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './app/home/home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/home/home.component.css'],
  directives: [HomeProjectComponent, NewsletterComponent]
})

export class HomeComponent {
  projects = PROJECTS;
}
```

---

This is my html code were i m trying to get the name, title and status of the project with ID
home.component.html

The {{project.name}}, {{project.title}} and {{project.status}} must be the same

```
get data with id 20
<home>
  <h1>{{project.name}}</h1>
  <h2>{{project.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{project.status}}</p>
</home>

// SOME HTML

get data with id 64
<home>
  <h1>{{project.name}}</h1>
  <h2>{{project.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{project.status}}</p>
</home>

// SOME HTML

get data with id 69
<home>
  <h1>{{project.name}}</h1>
  <h2>{{project.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{project.status}}</p>
</home>
```

Comment: How does the component code look like?

Comment: `@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './app/home/home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/home/home.component.css'],
  directives: [HomeProjectComponent, NewsletterComponent]
})`

Comment: And the component class? Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: ok. just update my code.

Answer (score 1):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './app/home/home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/home/home.component.css'],
  directives: [HomeProjectComponent, NewsletterComponent]
})

export class HomeComponent {
  projects = PROJECTS;

  projectId2 = this.extractProjectWithId(2);

  extractProjectWithId(id){
      let i;
      for(i = 0; i< this.projects.length; i++)
      {
         if(this.projects[i].id === id)
          return this.projects[i];
      }

      return null;
    }
}
```

---

```ts
<div *ngIf="projectId2"> // extract data with ID 2 from project 
  <h1>{{projectId2.name}}</h1>
  <h2>{{projectId2.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{projectId2.status}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This way i can only extract the data with id2.
And i want 3* same html element but extract others id

Comment: I just update my question so you can understand what i mean

Comment: you can just use `*ngFor` then

Comment: ngFor display all objects in order. i'd like to use a home-id-x then some html codes then home-id-xx some html code and home-id-xxx.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a method returning object with id 2. Something like:

```
getObjectById(id: number) {
  return PROJECTS.filter(x => x.id == id);
}
```

Reading it

```
<home> // extract data with ID 2 from project 
  <h1>{{ getObjectById(2)[0].name }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ getObjectById(2)[0].title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ getObjectById(2)[0].status }}</p>
</home>
```

**Update for new edit**:

Since you need all `project` from array why don't you print them using `*ngFor`:

```
<home *ngFor="let project of PROJECTS"> // extract data with ID 2 from project 
  <h1>{{ project.name }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ project.title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ project.status }}</p>
</home>
```

That simplifies interpolations `{{ }}` and you won't need any other functions to get specific element.
If you care about the sequence of `projects`, then create a member variable

```
projectInSequence: Project[];
```

and push projects in desired sequence, `ngFor` will change to `*ngFor="let project of projectInSequence`. Filling `projectInSequence` can be done in a life-cycle hook https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: Well, i don't need/want to display all the projects.
I have over 20 projects and i wan t to display only 9 of them, i want to have one project id-x then some html than project-id-y some html project-id-zz some html and so on

Comment: Then better go with `projectsInSequence` way